# jQuery countdown to jquery event

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am using jQuery to refresh a DIV content box every 5 seconds or so, the time is actually controllable by the end user.
I want to have a countdown timer on the page which will count down until the next page refresh (or query) based on the value that is set.

For now, it can be a static value of 5 seconds but I really can't work out how to get a countdown running along side my query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might post some of your code-trials

Comment: did one of the answers solve your problem? If so please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

```
var remaining = 5;

var myInterval = setInterval ( updateCountDown, 1000 );

function updateCountDown( )
{
  $("mydiv").text(remaining );
  remaining --;
  if (remaining == 0) {
    clearInterval(myInterval );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the [countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin will help...
there's an `onExpiry`-event and the `until`-property is very helpful.

another problem you might stumble upon is: js does not support real multithreading...

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Not sure if we understood you:
Do you want a counter beeing displayed on the page?

If not:

You can set a variable in your JavaScript, e.g.

```
var TimeOutValue = 5000;

function OnTimeOut()
{
    // Add here your code for refreshing the DIV content
   window.setTimeout(OnTimeOut, TimeOutValue);
}
```

In the Handler for textchanged event of the input field: e.g.

```
function InputTextChanged()
{
   TimeOutValue = document.getElementById("Id_of_Input_field").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I did something similar a while ago. I used a plugin for jQuery called [jquery.timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers):

this is my code:

```
    function timerTick() {
        counter--;
        $("#lblRepeat").html('searching again in ' + counter + ':');
        if (counter <= 0) {
            counter = 60;
            search();
        }
    }
    function chkActivate_click(ev) {
        var vr, t;
        t = $(this); 
        vr = t.is(':checked');
        if (vr) {
            t.everyTime(1000, 'busqueda', timerTick);
        } else {
            t.stopTime('busqueda');
        }
    }
```